# if hasClass on A, then click on B, addClass to B and C

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to do something like this.
If "a" has "active" class, when click on "b", then b and c will add different class.
How should I do this?

```js
if ( $('.a').hasClass('active') ) {
  $('.b').on('click', function() {
    $('.b').addClass('go1');
    $('.c').addClass('go2');
    }
  )}
```

```css
div {width:200px; height:50px;}
.a {background:yellow;}
.b {background:red;}
.c {background:blue;}

.go1 {background:green;}
.go2 {background:purple;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a active">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<div class="c">C</div>
```

Comment: you first click on b *then* you test the class of a inside the click handler

Comment: your code works fine as written. include jquery when using the snippet

Comment: @DCR don't update the code to correctly include jQuery. It's probably the main issue of the question and you can make it irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

You must check the class "active" of "a" inside the "click" callback :

```
$('.b').on('click', function() {
  if ($('.a').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.b').addClass('go1');
    $('.c').addClass('go2');
  }
})
```

Comment: oh i see~ thank you very much. What should I write after this if I need to write addClass or removeClass if the a div don't have "active" class? how to write the else if?

Answer (score -1):

You just need to change the order: When click on "b", if "a" has "active" class, then b and c will add different class. Another thing to consider is if you are dynamically changing the classes, you may not want to use class selectors (although you are not removing .a, .b, .c here).

https://jsfiddle.net/xbtsrqe8/

```
<div id="a" class="a active">A</div>
<div id="b" class="b">B</div>
<div id="c" class="c">C</div>

$("#b").click(function()
{
 if($("#a").hasClass("active"))
 {
   $("#b").addClass("go1");
   $("#c").addClass("go2");
 }
});
```